# Erlang Mysql: How to prevent SQL Injections

Tags: mysql, sql, erlang, sql-injection

I'm very new to erlang and I need to code something which inserts rows in a MySQL Database. 
How can I prevent SQL Injections with Erlang? Is there also something like prepared statements in other Languages or how should I do it?

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer depends on the driver you are using.

Erlang ODBC has a function param_query that binds a set of parameters to the query and it might also escape all the SQL special characters.

[erlang-mysql-driver](http://code.google.com/p/erlang-mysql-driver/) has prepared statements:

```
%% Register a prepared statement
mysql:prepare(update_developer_country,
              <<"UPDATE developer SET country=? where name like ?">>),

%% Execute the prepared statement
mysql:execute(p1, update_developer_country, [<<"Sweden">>,<<"%Wiger">>]),
```

(code from [Yariv's blog](http://yarivsblog.blogspot.com/2006/09/erlang-mysql-driver-reloaded.html))

As a last resort you can always [escape the characters](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#MySQL_Escaping)

```
 NUL (0x00) --> \0 
 BS  (0x08) --> \b
 TAB (0x09) --> \t
 LF  (0x0a) --> \n
 CR  (0x0d) --> \r
 SUB (0x1a) --> \z
 "   (0x22) --> \"
 %   (0x25) --> \%
 '   (0x27) --> \'
 \   (0x5c) --> \\
 _   (0x5f) --> \_
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll try it (using mysql driver)

Comment: Escaping the characters is dangerous and prone to errors. As a last resort, it's a pretty bad false sense of security.

Comment: hmm. somehow it doesn't work with mysql:prepare/mysql:execute. I receive a undef error when I call it.
Also, when using mysql:quote (that would also work I think) it logs the same error :( But I looked at the source and there seems to exist mysql:quote (but not prepare/execute...)

Comment: I used the mysql driver from ejabberd-modules: https://svn.process-one.net/ejabberd-modules/mysql/trunk/src/

Comment: It (the code in google-code) does seem to export prepare and execute but not quote in mysql.erl. You have followed the code examples and used mysql::start_link to connect to the database?

Comment: That seems to be an older version that does not include prepared statements.

Comment: I just tried with the version (and mysql:prepare) from yariv's blog but it doesn't seem to work either. 
" {undef,
                                   [{mysql,prepare,"

I opened the connection with mysql:connect. Maybe I need to use start_link. I'll try that.

//Edit: It doesn't work with start_link, too.

Comment: Changed now the way I call mysql:prepare (with the << and >> brackets) and now it seems to somehow work, but now execute fails. Trying to fix that issue now: {noproc,
                                   {gen_server,call,
                                    [mysql_dispatcher,
                                     {execute,2,insert_log_row,